# How can I create reusable properties in C#

Tags: c#, converters

What I usually do in coding is

```
 string s = "1.0";
 
 int i = Convert.ToInt32(s);
 
 double d = Convert.ToDouble(s);
```

But I was trying to *reus*e "`Convert.ToDouble(s)`" this *method* as "`s.ToDouble()` or `s.ToInt()`".

Is it possible?
If possible then how can I do that?
Please guide me.

Comment: You don't seem to be using the right terminology, which is making your question confusing. Can you give more context about where this code is currently located and what your goal is?

Comment: You can write an extension method, but why do you want to do this?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods try to take a look here

Comment: looks like you want a method that passes a string and does some conversions??

Comment: Yes, Ric .
I want to reuse Convert.ToDouble(Var) as Var.ToDouble().As we use ToString() properties.

Comment: Note that ToDouble and ToInt aren't properties, they're methods.

Comment: @shree.pat18 i was just wondering if we can use ToString() properties to convert something to string then why we can not use same properties to convert other forms. that's why i was trying to override meta methods but getting error. and not achieving the result.

Comment: Only a _very_ small number of strings can be converted to a double, so it doesn't make sense to allow such a method to be invoked on all strings.

Comment: Another problem with implementing such a method *directly* in the String class (instead of through extension) is you then include references on Int32, Double, etc yet those structs already refer to String through their ToString(), introducing circular dependencies which is Bad™ https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/11856/whats-wrong-with-circular-references

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems, that you a looking for [extensions methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods), for instance:

```
public static class MyConvertibleExtensions {
  public static double ToDouble<T>(this T value) where T : IConvertible {
    if (value is null)
      throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(value)); 

    return Convert.ToDouble(value);
  }
}
```

Having this implemented you can put

```
double d1 = "123".ToDouble();

double d2 = true.ToDouble();
```

Please, note, however, that `Convert.ToDouble(...)` is more natural way to convert one type to another.

Answer (score 0):

What you mean you need, is to create a new type (class) to have an object than could call methods like this `.ToInt()`. You can create a class wich extends String class, and add to your new class a method called `ToInt()`. This method will return an Int32 value (int), taking value from main object (your string extended object).

This is not a good idea, because you have Convert methods, as you said. But if you want, you can do it.

Could this help you?

Comment: You can't extend String though since it's `sealed`, there are extension methods but it's actually syntactic sugar, the private member still isn't accessible and the resulting object is still identical.